# Spring instantiates two times a bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have several beans in my businessAplicationContext.xml, everything working fine until I added a new one called:

> <bean id="TcmLogManager" class="ar.com.southend.tim.backend.util.logging.TcmLogManager"/>

This TcmLogManager simply instantiates a java.util.logging.StreamHandler so that some log entries can be stored memory.

The problem is Spring instantiates this bean 2 times... while there's only 1 definition (and if I duplicate the line in the .xml with a different id, it creates 4 objects... and so on...)

I also defined the scope to "singleton" but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace and some more information? It's difficult to figure out what's going on with the current information.

Comment: Can you try putting a constructor(with a log statement) in this bean and any other bean and confirm that said bean is instantiated twice while other bean is not?

Comment: Do you have AOP Proxy set up somewhere in your spring configuration?

Comment: Could you set the log level to DEBUG and update the question with the log output?

Comment: @Ryan Stewart, I've already checked the "defining beans" list, and all the beans appear in the correct order... and just one time. The workflow while creating the beans seems to be all right, it first defines the businessBeanFactory and then creates one application context with all the beans prior to hibernate initialization. Here's the log:
<pre>
[11/08/11 9:43:40:995 ART] 0000002a ServletWrappe I SRVE0242I: [TIMAdminEAR] [/TIMAdminWeb] [FilterProxyServlet]: Inicialización satisfactoria.
[11/08/11 9:43:45:691 ART] 0000002e ServletWrappe I SRVE0242I: [TIMAdminEAR] [/TIMAdminWeb] [loginServlet]

Answer (score 2):

Check your context files for `<context:component-scan>` or other scan tags. These force Spring to scan your source files for component classes. If you need more then one scan, you should trim the scanning using exclude/include filters. You define filters with nested xml nodes.
As @adarshr pointed out, the second constructor call can be a proxy bean, used to link AOP aspects.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause from the way you describe the problem is that the context file where that bean definition lives is used twice in the creation of ApplicationContexts--maybe twice in the same one, somehow, or for two different ones. When Spring starts up, it logs at INFO level all the beans that exist in a particular BeanFactory. You can check over that list to see exactly which beans live where. Search for the phrase "defining beans" in the logs to find it.